# Image search software on Mac and Windows?

Tags: images

I want to search image files from their pixel data. I routinely copy and paste images from ImageJ and other softwares onto Word, KeyNote, etc., and I often want to go back to original images on a local machine to find out when and how those images were taken in scientific experiment. Is there any (preferably open source) software for that?

I can do and like coding, so any recommendation for a programming library will also be helpful.